# Can i use a button's id for a click function in my jquery script?

Tags: jquery, function, tags, click, href

Every time i try to add the below code to my site, every `<a href>` link on the page opens.  How do I get this code to work without it opening every `<a href>` link, and instead of using  for the click function could i use a button and its id instead?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      p.one { position:relative; width:400px; height:90px; }
      div.two { position:absolute; width:400px; height:65px; 
        font-size:36px; text-align:center; 
        color:yellow; background:red;
        padding-top:25px; 
        top:0; left:0; display:none; }
        span.three { display:none; }
      </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="one">
        Let it be known that the party of the first part
        and the party of the second part are henceforth
        and hereto directed to assess the allegations
        for factual correctness... (<a href="#">click!</a>)
        <div class="two"><span class="three">Click here to continue...</span></div>

      </p>
<script>
        $("a").click(function () {
          $("div").fadeIn(3000, function () {
            $("span").fadeIn(100);
          });
          return false;
        }); 

      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should learn first html and css selectors

Comment: could not understand the problem. please rephrase your question.

Comment: Why haven't you tried what you're doing? You have the code, is it easier to post the question and format the code than try to use the button the and ids as you mention?

Comment: code shown works fine here  http://jsfiddle.net/rZKP3/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this` keyword which refers the clicked element.

```
$(function() {
   $(".one a").click(function(event) {
      $(this).next('div').fadeIn(3000, function(){
         $('span', this).fadeIn();
      })
      event.preventDefault();
   }); 
})
```

Note that your markup is invalid, using DIV tags within P tags makes your document invalid and is not *semantic*, most of the browsers put the DIV element outside of the P tag, your current code works only because you are selecting all the DIV elements, if you traverse the DOM according to your current markup(*as I did*) you will get unexpected results.

```
<div class="one">
    <p>
       Let it be known that the party of the first part
       and the party of the second part are henceforth
       and hereto directed to assess the allegations
       for factual correctness...
    </p>
    <a href="#">click!</a>
    <div class="two"><span class="three">Click here to continue...</span></div>
</div>
```

Also note that when a parent element is hidden all of it's children are hidden too, so there is no need to hide the children and show them one by one., hiding and showing the parent element is enough.

http://jsfiddle.net/BhJJa/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**id selector**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) by jquery.

```
$("#YourButtonId").click(function () {
      $("div").fadeIn(3000, function () {
        $("span").fadeIn(100);
      });
      return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your time...working fine by itself when i test in notepad and then in broswer...but on my website its still opening up other stuff when i click it

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are binding a click event to every `<a>` in your HTML document. You will need to give you button/a an id to select it with jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$("#btnID").click(function() {
 $("div").fadeIn(3000, function () {
  $("span").fadeIn(100);
 });
 return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btnID">click!</a>
```

you can also use this with a `<button>` tag.

Comment: yeah its working fine when i test it out alone...but when i put it in my site its still opeing other stuff when i click on it

Comment: thats because there is an error in my code in the selector. i changed it